# How to test function that observe live data

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

Trying to write unit test on a function that observe livedata from the another class
Could someone help me with it please.

The class I'm trying to test:

```
override fun observe(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
    appCoordinatorManager.getState().observe(activity) {
        when(it) {
            is AppCoordinatorManager.State.AssociateWithReferralProgramSuccess -> {
                navigator.navigateToDashboard(null)
            }
}
```

AppCoordinatorManager.getState()

```
private val state = LiveEvent<State>()

fun getState(): LiveData<State> = state

sealed class State {
    object AssociateWithReferralProgramSuccess: State()
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
fun `Receiving AssociateWithReferralProgramSuccess when observing state from AppCoordinatorManager`() {

    whenever(appCoordinatorManager.getState()).thenReturn(LiveEvent<AppCoordinatorManager.State>())
    
    appCoordinator.observe(activity)

    appCoordinatorManager.setPrivateField("state", LiveEvent<AppCoordinatorManager.State.AssociateWithReferralProgramSuccess>())

    verify(navigator).navigateToDashboard(null)
}
```

Comment: Funny thing, last time I check there is no built-in solution, what most people do is to use `CountDownLatch`. You might want to make it a helper method or an extension.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments. You can create a file inside your test/java/com.yourpath

For Example: `LiveDataUtilTest.kt` and add the following extension function that i got from one of google sample.

```
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

/**
 * Gets the value of a [LiveData] or waits for it to have one, with a timeout.
 *
 * Use this extension from host-side (JVM) tests. It's recommended to use it alongside
 * `InstantTaskExecutorRule` or a similar mechanism to execute tasks synchronously.
 */
@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.NONE)
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValueTest(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
    afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValueTest.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
    this.observeForever(observer)

    try {
        afterObserve.invoke()

        // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
        if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
            throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
        }

    } finally {
        this.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```

If you're using the Coroutine `Main` dispatcher in your `viewmodel` then add following class.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description

/**
 * During the unit-test, it enables the main dispatcher to use TestCoroutineDispatcher.
 * After the test, it resets and cleanup.
 */
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        cleanupTestCoroutines()
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Now in your test class add the following rule to make things synchronous and replace main dispatcher.

```
@get:Rule
var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@get:Rule
var mainRule = MainCoroutineRule()
```

Now get the value of your livedata in your test.

```
// userProfileViewModel.user is a live data object

val user = userProfileViewModel.user.getOrAwaitValueTest()

    assertThat(user.id).isEqualTo(userTest.id)
```

You might also like this blog for detailed explanation: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04

Comment: I need to test observe function and not the livedata directly

Comment: @EdgarKhimich That's the thing. In your case the right way is actually testing the `appCoordinatorManager.getState()` observing the change on it, and then calling the function to set your new state. Assert that to verify. This way you test the function.  :)

Comment: How would you do the same thing with a StateFlow instead?